# Home page links are not working , admin login not working via http://localhost/bi/?q=admin/modules link

Tags: installation

I moved a drupal installation from one server to another. Steps I followed:

- Copied whole directory structure from old server.
- Exported database from old server.
- added files to newdomain/drupal
- Imported database
- edited settings.php with new database information.

As of right now the home page is working (Except for some broken non-db images, but I know the reason for that and can fix it) But none of the links to any of the nodes or any of the admin paths I know seem to exist. I get a 404 File Not Found error.

I wonder if it's related to the fact that this installation is in a subdirectory and the other one was not, but is that enough to make every page except the homepage not function?

Comment: Have you checked that `http://localhost/example?q=user` is working or not?

Comment: set base path in settings.php

Comment: check that .htaccess exists in root folder or not